# Chrome Developer Tools - How to lock css classlist?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I need to inspect a search bar. The search bar is initially hidden and only shows after clicking on the search icon.

However, if I click on my developer tools then the search bar dissapears again... If the search box should appear, then a class named `active` is added. So I tried to add the class manually but if I inspect other elements, then the active class is removed again...

Is there a way to lock the classlist? I could write a javascript interval method which sets the classlist, as a workaround.

e.g.

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery("#debug")[0].classList = "label icon faSearch active";
}, 1000 );
```

But is there an easier way?

Comment: Or just uncheck the `visibility: hidden`/`display: none` (whatever you used to hide it) in the element inspector CSS section.

Comment: @Red, it is added back again, probably by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to debug your CSS, you can press F8 in the Sources tab of Developer console and you'll pause every Javascript code execution. That will prevent any Javascript code from altering the CSS classes.

Then you can change any CSS class manually.

Comment: First, open developer tools and select the "Sources" (english version name) tab. Then click in the search bar icon to open the search bar. Then press F8. You should see how Chrome blurs the background and tells you the execution has been stopped. Then you can go to the "Elements" (english version name) in Developer tools and inspect all the DOM, adding any CSS class you want by double clicking in the "class=..." attribute of the search bar.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please? I can't find the search bar?

Comment: I was referring to the search bar you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

When we inspect a page by chrome developer tools, By selecting the particular element, the styles of the element will be shown, where in we will have option to freeze the element's state by clicking ":hov" as shown in the screenshot below,

[image]

Comment: Does not work. The searchbar does not show even thoug I set hover on the icon.

Comment: the hover checkbox is only there for setting the hover active so classes which are using the hover pseudo are getting triggered. This does not implicitly lead to execution ov javascript so nothing happens..